# click event not firing on input type=submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am obviously doing something dumb, I can't quite see what's wrong.  Whenever I click the "Send" button, the click event fails to fire.

```
function CreateNewMessage()
{
    var receiver = $("#receiver").value;
    var msg_body = ("#msg_body").value;
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        alert("it works!");
        $.post("new/", {"receiver" : receiver, "msg_body" : msg_body});
    });
}

(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        CreateNewMessage();
    });
})();
```

and the HTML button

```
<input id="submit" value="Send" type="submit">
```

Who can spot my error?

EDIT:

So here is what my code looks like now after taking everyone's suggestions into consideration.

```
function CreateNewMessage()
{
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        var receiver = $("#receiver").val();
        var msg_body = $("#msg_body").val();
        alert("it works!");
        $.post("message/new/", {"receiver" : receiver, "msg_body" : msg_body});
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    CreateNewMessage();
});
```

It still is not sending a request properly, and the console is not logging an errors.  I tried using the submit event as opposed to the click event in the code above but got the same results.

EDIT 2
So the code is working on jsFiddle but not in my browser.  I am really confused

EDIT 3:
Maybe this has something to do with it... Note that the submit button does not exist when the page is initially loaded. It is generated when a specific javascript event fires.

Comment: Check the console in your browser, it will give you a clue on what's going wrong. Learn how to debug your code.

Comment: Add the indexer `[0]` to your `$()` calls when you're working with single items.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `$()` function for `#msg_body`, it should be like so:

```
var receiver = $("#receiver")[0].value;
var msg_body = $("#msg_body")[0].value;
```

Also, you don't need to wrap the `ready` in a function, you can call it directly in your script; you can also set your CreateNewMessage function as the handler directly, like so:

```
$(document).ready( CreateNewMessage );
```

Comment: I'm not the OP. It should be `.val()` or `$("#msg_body")[0].value`

Answer (score 1):

Value with jQuery is .val(). Also, why not listen to the submit event? If you don't want the post to go through, simply make it return false.

Comment: I needed to edit the request header to include a CSRD token before submitting the post. My understanding is that I can only do this with an AJAX request.

Comment: Then fire the Ajax request from the submit function. As long as your submit function returns false, the browser won't try to post the form.

Comment: let me ask a dumb question.  I am quite new to javascript... is the submit function that function attached to the onclick attribute?

Comment: You need to attach the submit() function to your form, not the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the $ before ("#msg_body") so your script will crash there.

```
function CreateNewMessage()
{
    var receiver = $("#receiver").value;
    var msg_body = $("#msg_body").value;
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
        alert("it works!");
        $.post("new/", {"receiver" : receiver, "msg_body" : msg_body});
    });
}

(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        CreateNewMessage();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CreateNewMessage()
{
    var receiver = $("#receiver").value;
    var msg_body = $("#msg_body").value;

    alert("it works!");
    $.post("new/", {"receiver" : receiver, "msg_body" : msg_body});
}

$(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    CreateNewMessage();
  });
});
```